# How can I secure my Python app's MySQL connection details from users?

Tags: python, database, security, connection

I'm making a python app that connects to a database. The only problem is that I need the connection username and password to be hidden for security. Here us my current unsecure code.

```
#not real connection.

import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="host",
  user="uname",
  password="test password"
)
```

I need the connection details to be hidden from the users. What is the best way to do this.

tHanks,
Matthew

Comment: Other than making this a web app, so the users don't have direct access to the script, I don't think you can.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. How do apps on your desktop connect to a online database if it is not possible?

Comment: The database connection is done on the server, not the client.

Comment: Ok, could you give an example of how to do that with python please. I'm new to creating apps. Thanks, Matthew

Comment: That's too broad a topic. Read a Flask tutorial.